# Outlook add - in is greyed out on outlook 2013 Desktop for some users

Tags: outlook, office365, office365api, office365-apps

I am having this issue with outlook add-in. So the add-in is published inside company by IT, and everybody sees it on OWA and it is functioning the way it supposed to.

**Now for some users when they open Outlook 2013 Desktop it is greyed out like this**:[image]

**And when I go to manage add-in on owa this is what I see which seems alright:**

[image]

I tried to disable other add-ins to see if those are causing conflicts and that did not work. Here is the manifest file: I deleted some lines that are company related and modified url's but the rest is the same.

```html
    <FormSettings>
    <!--
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/AppRead/Home/Home.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
    -->
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation               DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/MailForms/AppCompose/1.0.0.3/Home/Home.html"/>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
    <!--
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
    -->
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.4">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
     <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
          <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

          <!-- Message Read -->
          <!--<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            --><!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> --><!--
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              --><!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab --><!--
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                --><!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button --><!--
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                --><!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu --><!--
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>-->
          
          <!-- Message Compose -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="messageComposeTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
          <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/MailForms/Images/icon16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/MailForms/Images/icon32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/MailForms/Images/icon80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue=" ~remoteAppUrl/MailForms/Functions/FunctionFile.html"/>
        <!--<bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/AppRead/Home/Home.html"/>-->
        <bt:Url id="messageComposeTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/MailForms/AppCompose/1.0.0.3/Home/Home.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="My Add-in Group"/>
        <bt:String id="customTabLabel"  DefaultValue="My Add-in Tab"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Messageware Mail Forms"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Get all properties"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties. This is an example of a button that opens a task pane."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: Did the add-in ever work in Outlook 2013? Does it work in Outlook 2016? You might want to share the manifest used to publish the add-in

Answer (score 1):

Ok - so your DefaultMinVersion is 1.4:

```
<bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.4">
```

Per the [Requirement Set documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets), requirement set 1.4 was added to Outlook 2013 via [kb 3118280](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3118280/ms16-107-description-of-the-security-update-for-outlook-2013-september), which is version 15.0.4859.1000. So you should check the version of Outlook 2013 you're running. Any client which is out of date would offer requirement set 1.3 or lower and would show the icon as greyed out.

Your comment about Salesforce reminds me of something I just debugged. The version of Outlook itself doesn't matter for requirements sets. It's the version of osf.dll and osfshared.dll that matter. So quite likely that's out of date. Try the [latest OSF update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4018333/april-3-2018-update-for-office-2013-kb4018333) and see if that gets Salesforce working.

Bug I filed on the requirements sets documentation: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/issues/1461

Comment: I updated my post with my outlook version. Not sure where to look for that "1.4" or 
"1.3"

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify the Outlook build version you need and the requirement set which should be offered by it. From your posted build version, you *should* be offered 1.4. We can confirm if this is the case by installing the Message Header Analyzer addin (https://github.com/stephenegriffin/MHA). In that add-in, you can click the gear and then Diagnostics to get a panel of information, including the requirement set that the client is advertising. This will also be a good test to see if your client is having trouble with all add-ins or just yours.

Comment: Turning off salesforce did the job. Not the best solution but works for now